# How to apply split string to a vector?

Tags: r

I want to split based on :: but it doesnt work for the entire vector

```
str<- c("bob::jhh","jjj::dfff")
data<- as.data.frame(x)
data

data$new.col <-strsplit(as.character(b[,1]),"::")[[1]][2]
data
```

output

```
       data new.col
1  bob::jhh     jhh
2 jjj::dfff     jhh #<<--this should be dfff not jhhh.
```

any idea how to make it return jhh dfff instead of jhh jhh?

Comment: What is `x`?  What is `b`?

Answer (score 1):

sapply can be used here:

```
str<- c("bob::jhh","jjj::dfff")
ss = strsplit(str, split="::")
sapply(ss, function(x) x[2])
[1] "jhh"  "dfff"
```

It can be put in the dataframe:

```
nn = sapply(ss, function(x) x[2])
dataf$new = nn
dataf
        str  new
1  bob::jhh  jhh
2 jjj::dfff dfff
```

Answer (score 0):

`strsplit` returns a list, so you need to process that list. For example

```
str <- c("bob::jhh","jjj::dfff", "another::string", "foo::bar")
dat <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(str, split="::"))
```

This creates a matrix, first column is everything on left of `::` and second column everything on the right of `::`